# Port Xamarin Android project to .net6.0-android

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a Xamarin Android Project that I want to migrate to .net6.0-android so I can use the new versions of MvvmCross.  I have tried the upgrade-assistant.  It claims to only upgrade Xamarin forms apps.  I tried try-convert and it only seems to use msbuild through .net5.0.  Can anyone tell me the correct steps to do this migration?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Create a new .NET 6 Android project and then cut/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to maintain consistency in my Git Repository, so here is what I did.  I made sure my app used the new PackageReference (to do this, if your project has a packages.config, you can right click it and it will give you an option to migrate).  I created a blank .net6.0-android app.  I copied the contents of my original app .proj to notepad to keep track of what NuGet packages I had been using.  I then overwrote the contents of my original app .proj file with the contents of the blank app .proj.  I used Nuget to add back in the required packages.  I had to delete AssemblyInfo.cs in the Properties folder and Resource.Designer.cs in the Resources folder.  I deleted the obj and bin folders in the project folder.  After that, I was able to compile and run fine.